# Automatically run excel solver when some numbers in the sheet change

Tags: excel, solver

I am trying to run a cost analysis for a school in excel. At different pricing we get different number of students and based on that we need to analyze cost for hiring different kind of faculty for each department. We calculate requirements for each department using solver. And we need to run solver 10 times to calculate cost for 10 years. And is we change the fee we need to repeat this process. Is there any way I can automate solver triggers? If not whats the best alternative? Is there a different software that will make my life easy?

Answer (score 1):

You need to subscribe to the [WorkSheet_Changed](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/run-macros-change.htm) event.

That event will run each time anything is changed on that worksheet. You need to make an if statement like:

```
 if the cells in the appropriate range have been changed:
     do the operation that you need
```

Answer (score 0):

Start recording the macro for your solver. Then go to the Visual Basic Editor and edit the macros until you feel that they can run properly (i.e. regardless of where you start them from). Now, go into the code for your worksheet (double-click the worksheet in Visual Basic Project Explorer) and copy the macros in a worksheet_change macro.

You'll want to only run the macro when your fees cell change (I've assumed A1 in the sample code below), and disable events while you run the goal seek macro so you don't end up in a looooong loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, [A1]) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False

'your goal seeking code

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```